# Humans breeding with dragons

Tags: biology, evolution, mythical-creatures, dragons, low-fantasy

Firstly, by dragon I am referring to the type with 4 legs a tail and wings. Their actual sizes vary greatly, from the size of your average house cat to feasting on planets in one bite. Most are sentient with higher than human intelligence and with magic are capable of shifting into humanoid forms that are on average 6 to 12 inches taller than your average human and mostly look human aside from their eyes. Their eyes work very similarly to D&D dragon eyes and are the only part of them that they can never change or disguise.

How many years of interbreeding with humans in that humanoid form would it take for dragons to become myth as they are in our world today and the only population remaining is basically a normal human with dragon eyes? Also, what would the evolutionary odds be that someone could be born in that time period where dragons are myth and be 100% pure dragon?

Real dragons still exist in the greater universe beyond this planet, they're just under orders not to disturb this planet along with all the other inter galactic species.

Comment: Hello @PirateFox, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, we permit one and only one question per post. Please take the time to read our [tour] and two Help Center pages ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]) to better understand the rules of the Stack. Thanks! Please note that this question falls into my "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: As many as wanting!" category. Without providing the genetic details governing your dragonfolk, this question has no answer other than story-based opinion (two factual reasons to close questions). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: What's holding you back from choosing a number that makes sense for your story? Myths are the result of lack of credible documentation and existing empirical evidence. Those human eyes are a bit of a problem. Even if the result of a recessive gene, they'd pop up somewhat randomly no matter how long you wait, and each time they do your myth becomes very real. We'd love to help you develop the rules of your world! Can you help us out by explaining what I suspect is the real problem?

Comment: One last thing, you're asking questions that sound like they should be answerable with a basic application of chromosomal or genetic knowledge. But humans have been around for a very long time, and yet we have about three dozen skin colors, more than a half dozen eye colors, who knows how many hair colors, height/weight variations, propensities for talents and skills, and don't even get us started about the variations in gender issues. My point? After all that time of just humans being with just humans, *there's still not just one human type.*

Comment: Even from a purely genetic standpoint, it's missing some important details that would be needed to calculate this. How many dragons are breeding with how many humans, over how many generations? Is this just one rebel sowing wild oats, or is it an entire colony? How many genes are responsible for "dragonness" and do you need all of them to express anything beyond the eyes?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get there from here.

When discussing breeding possibilities, we have a thing called speciation. A species is literally a collection of creatures that can breed with one another. If, for instance, you try to breed a human with a gorilla, it would be like trying to decompress a png file with the zip decoder. It results in nonsense. You don't even have the same number of chromosomes. If you go down to frogs, they have W and Z chromosomes instead of X and Y.

Without magic, either the dragon is genetically little different from, for instance, a Viking, or you don't have kids. With magic, you can do whatever you want.

But, lets have some fun with this. Let's take the Viking case and say that there are nine magic genes that differentiate a person from a dragon. In a human, the genes are unexpressed, and in dragons they're 100% expressed. You'd quickly wind up with 40% dragons running around. For extra texture, you can tie each gene to an element, so you wind up with dragons in nine flavors and 45 ways to mix the genes, so you could have mud dragons and lightning dragons, etc..

How long would it take for this to distribute through mankind? That depends on how freely breeding happens. For any population, if the people randomly couple, it'll only be about 20 generations before everyone in the group can trace their roots back to a single common ancestor.

Now you have to decide if the genes are dominant or recessive. If they're dominant, then everybody who has a gene will show dragon traits. If they're recessive, then only 1 in 3 gene carriers will show dragon traits.

How often would you see functional dragons? It would be like blue eyes in European populations. Blue eyes are recessive, so you only see blue eyes when both genes are for blue eyes.

Next we have to talk about whether or not it's a breeding advantage to have dragon genes. Unless there's a downside that you aren't mentioning, I'm pretty sure that most people would want to jump in bed with a dragonkind, so it would spread pretty quickly. The recessive dragon traits would definitely hide in the first generation, only showing up when two dragonspawn bred with one another.

You can read up on [how genetic inheritance works](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5525089/), but most descriptions of it are kind of dense. Here's a simpler version.

Probability for every gene would be independent, so let's take one, like the "fire dragon" gene.

```
Dad:   ff
Mom:   NN
kids:  fN fN fN fN
```

If the kids breed with a commoner, half of them would wind up with the recessive dragon gene.

```
kid:       fN
commoner:  NN
grandkids: fN NN fN NN
```

If they bred with a dragonkind, half would get the dragon traits.

```
kid:        fN
dragonkind: ff
grandkids:  ff fN ff fN
```

If two half-dragons bred, a quarter of their kids would have dragon traits. Remember that only ff has dragon traits.

```
kid1:  fN
kid2:  fN
grandkids:  ff fN Nf NN
```

I think you can see where this is going, and that's going to happen independently for every dragon gene. Let's take a random coupling of a couple of first-generations, with the fire, ice, earth, and aether genes:

```
kid1:   fN iN eN aN
kid2:   fN iN eN aN
grkid1: ff NN Ne aN. - shows fire, can never pass on ice
grkid2: Nf iN Ne Na. - poor kid got nothing, but can pass it all on
grkid3: ff ii ee aa. - Lucky kid, just as good as his granddad
grkid4: NN NN NN NN  - indistinguishable from 2, and can't pass anything on
```

Comment: Please remember those tags, Robert. The OP can get there from here because [Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609). Since it's a stated condition in the OP's question, your comments about realism aren't relevant. That leaves only your last paragraph. Can you expand on that?

Comment: @JBH, Real life can't get in the way, but OP is asking for details on how an impossible process would work, and that means we should close the question as "opinion based" or "story based." Based on your reaction, though, even you don't seem to realize that it's nonsensical, so it required an answer to clarify that it was nonsensical. Do you think it would be better if I started my post with "this is nonsensical"? FWIW, I was working on this response before bed, and I think the cat posted it for me. I'm gonna go fix it now.

Comment: First, thanks for the expanded explanation. that was an excellent explanation. Second, we deal with helping people create the rules of *imaginary worlds.* So pointing out how nonsensical the question is only exemplifies the problem - you're still trying to see this from the perspective of Real Life. I do try to not vote to close questions from new users, opting instead for education - which includes reminding respondents that this Stack is not physics-lite. The process isn't impossible because it exists on the OP's world. The goal is to use what we know of Real Life to rationalize that rule.

Comment: @JBH, thanks for elucidating. All that makes sense. I might have trouble with things that don't match our physics staying out of the "opinion" zone. :)